# Output iterator's value_type

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

The STL commonly defines an output iterator like so:

```
template<class Cont>
class insert_iterator
: public iterator<output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void> {
    // ...
```

**Why do output iterators define `value_type` as `void`?** It would be useful for an algorithm to know what type of value it is supposed to output.

For example, a function that translates a URL query `"key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"` into any container that holds key-value strings elements.

```
template<typename Ch,typename Tr,typename Out>
void parse(const std::basic_string<Ch,Tr>& str, Out result)
{
    std::basic_string<Ch,Tr> key, value;
    // loop over str, parse into p ...
        *result = typename iterator_traits<Out>::value_type(key, value);
}
```

The [SGI reference page of `value_type`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/value_type.html) hints this is because it's not possible to dereference an output iterator. But that's not the only use of `value_type`: I might want to instantiate one in order to assign it to the iterator.

**What alternative approach is there for constructing a value to output with the output iterator?** Two approaches I considered:

- Accept a functor parameter that would return an object of the correct type. I still want to have a version of the algorithm that doesn't take that function object parameter though.
- Require that the output container holds `pair<string,string>`, or else a type convertible from that. I wonder if I can do without this requirement, perhaps allow any element that can construct from two `std::string` s.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is generalize the algorithm such that it works with containers of any type that can construct from two `string` s, not just `map<string,string>`. Then, the template can instantiate into `*result = pair<string,string>(key,value)` as well as `*result = unicorn_pony(key,value)`.

Comment: If I may add a reference: a paper [pdf] about output iterators, also complains about this issue. http://semantics.org/publications/02_02_multiout.pdf

Comment: The example given in that paper is exactly why output iterators are not required to define a value type.  He arbitrarily decided that `MultiOut::value_type` should be `double`, but in reality *any* type that can be implicitly converted to both `double` and `int` are reasonable values to use for the assignment operator.

Comment: @Dennis oh my! In my overly-excited dig for information I haven't properly digested everything it says in the paper! In fact, I only read through whatever my search terms referred me to in the document. :s I have given it more thought now, and I think I see now why output iterators' `value_type` is for all practical purposes meaningless...

Comment: Not quite meaningless. I'm writing UTF-8 and UTF-16 conversion functions that use iterators, and I want to know whether the resulting value will fit into the target iterator (to throw an exception if it won't), but there's no way to retrieve that information from an `std::back_inserter`. I've gotten around it by adding an additional template parameter to the decode functions, but that complicates using them. Unnecessarily, in my opinion.

Comment: One solution for this is to use a constraint. If you're using C++11, something like `class = decltype(*result = declval<pair<string, string>>())` should do the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real value type of the iterator could well be the iterator itself. `operator*` may easily just return a reference to `*this` because the real work is done by the assignment operator. You may well find that `*it = x;` and `it = x;` have exactly the same effect with output iterators (I suppose special measures might be taken to prevent the latter from compiling).

As such, defining the real value type would be just as useless. Defining it as a `void`, on the other hand, can prevent errors like:

```
 typename Iter::value_type v = *it; //useless with an output iterator if it compiled
```

I suppose this is just the limit of the concept of output iterators: they are objects which "abuse" operator overloading, so as to *appear* pointerlike, whereas in reality something completely different is going on.

Your problem is interesting, though. If you want to support any container, then the output iterators in question would probably be `std::insert_iterator`, `std::front_insert_iterator` and `std::back_insert_iterator`. In this case you could do something like the following:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

//Iterator has value_type, use it
template <class T, class IterValue>
struct value_type
{
    typedef IterValue type;
};

//output iterator, use the container's value_type
template <class Container>
struct value_type<Container, void>
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type type;
};

template <class T, class Out>
void parse_aux(Out out)
{
    *out = typename value_type<T, typename Out::value_type>::type("a", "b");
}

template <template <class> class Out, class T>
void parse(Out<T> out)
{
    parse_aux<T>(out);
}

//variadic template in C++0x could take care of this and other overloads that might be needed
template <template <class, class> class Out, class T, class U>
void parse(Out<T, U> out)
{
    parse_aux<T>(out);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > vec;
    parse(std::back_inserter(vec));
    std::cout << vec[0].first << ' ' << vec[0].second << '\n';

    std::map<std::string, std::string> map;
    parse(std::inserter(map, map.end()));
    std::cout << map["a"] << '\n';

    //just might also support normal iterators
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > vec2(1);
    parse(vec2.begin());
    std::cout << vec2[0].first << ' ' << vec2[0].second << '\n';
}
```

It would still only get you this far. I suppose one could take this further, so it can also manage, say, a `std::ostream_iterator<printable_type>`, but at some point it would get so complex that it takes a god to decipher the error messages, should something go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the value_type of an iterator is to define the type that is returned when that iterator is dereferenced.  For output iterators, the only legitimate use of the dereference operator is when it is used in conjunction with the assignment operator--in the form of `*output_iterator = value`.  The type that is returned when dereferencing an output iterator does not necessarily have any direct relationship with the types that can be stored via the output iterator.  The only needed relationship is that there be some way of assigning the latter types to the former type.

Moreover, the output iterator can store values of multiple types, and these types do not have to have any relationship with one another.  Take for example the `null_output_iterator` described in [Discarding the output of a function that needs an output iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335930/335972#335972).  That iterator can accept for storage any type of value.

Comment: When you say _"The purpose of the value_type of an iterator is to define the type that is returned when that iterator is dereferenced"_, can you please specify the reference for that? A wording in the standard, perhaps? In section 24.3.1 of the standard I see no details about what `value_type` is for, only that output iterators may set it to void. In the TCPL3e, section 19.2.2, Stroustrup says only that "`value_type` is the type of element".

Comment: From section 24.1 of the standard, "All iterators i support the expression *i, resulting in a value of some class, enumeration, or built-in type T, called the value type of the iterator."

From section 24.3.1, "[...] it is required that if Iterator is the type of an iterator, [...] iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type be defined as the iterator's [...] value type [...] ."

Also from section 24.3.1, "In the case of an output iterator, [...] iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type [... is ...] defined as void."

Comment: Ok, I know that output iterators have `value_type` set to `void`. With `*i` being the `value_type` of `i`, and the programmer not allowed to dereference `i`, there's still a leap into allowing `*i` to be `void`. It needn't be `void`. There are other, valid uses for `value_type`. I'm not debating this, I just don't understand the leap from "you can't dereference an output iterator" to "let's define the `value_type` of an output iterator to `void`".

Comment: Since you cannot to dereference an output iterator for the purposes of obtaining a value, there is no value type for an output iterator.  Setting the value_type type in iterator_traits to void stipulates exactly that: there is no value type.  It may be more appropriate to set value_type to the actual type returned by the operator * method, but that is really an implementation detail of the specific output iterator.  Also, that would cause conflict for those iterators that are both input iterators and output iterators.

Comment: Just because a null output iterator can exist does not mean all output iterators should refuse to reveal their value type.