# Is it possible to deduce the contained type for std::insert_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, sfinae

I have a function that expects a templated iterator type.

It currently dereferences the iterator to inspect the type being iterated.

```
template < typename Iterator >
void func( Iterator i )
{
  // Inspect the size of the objects being iterated
  const size_t type_size = sizeof( *i );

  ...
}
```

I recently discovered that several of the standard iterator types, such as `std::insert_iterator` define `*i` as simply a reference to `i`.

That is, `sizeof(*i)` is the size of the iterator itself; the same as `sizeof(i)` or `sizeof(***i)`

Is there a universal way (supporting C++ 03) to determine the size or type of objects being iterated by any standard iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want the `value_type` of an OutputIterator, because there is no way to extract a value from an Output Iterator. However, the three insert iterator adaptors all define `value_type` to be `void` and provide a `container_type` type member, so you could fall back to the `value_type` of `T::container_type` if the `value_type` of `T` turns out to be `void`.

(By "`value_type` of" I really mean `std::iterator_traits<T::container_type>::value_type` and `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type`.)

Or you could just not try to use Output Iterators as though they had values :)

*Edit: SFINAE isn't necessary:* (even without C++11 niceness)

```
template<typename U, typename T> struct helper {typedef U type;};

// ostream*_iterator handling courtesy Drew Dormann
template <typename T, typename charT, typename traits>
struct helper<void, std::ostream_iterator<T, charT, traits> > {typedef T type;};

template <typename charT, typename traits>
struct helper<void, std::ostreambuf_iterator<charT, traits> > {typedef charT type;};

// std::raw_storage_iterator still needs an override
// as well as any non-standard output iterators which don't define a container_type.

template<typename T> struct helper<void, T>
{typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::container_type>::value_type type;};

typedef<typename It> struct my_value_type
  : public helper<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type, It> {};
```

Comment: I effectively want the type being inserted, not extracted.  Your container_type proposal is interesting.  I'd probably need to work some SFINAE magic, since raw pointers are valid iterators but don't define that typedef.

Comment: @DrewDormann: std::iterator_traits<T*>::value_type should be `T`, though, no?

Comment: @DrewDormann, of course, that won't work for ostream_iterator. For that one, you're just SOL.

Comment: Thanks, your solution did the job.  I fixed one typo and added support for iostream iterators.  Consider me SIL.

Comment: @DrewDormann: sorry about the missing typename and thanks for fixing it. I took istream_iterator out because it should always have a value_type (it's an input iterator), and added ostreambuf_iterator. I didn't add raw_storage_iterator, which is the only other standard output iterator as far as I can tell by searching the standard for output_iterator_tag.

Answer (score 4):

This is what the [`iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) are for.

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type type;
const std::size_t type_size = sizeof(type);
```

Edit: This does not work for all Output Iterators.

Comment: Is there a gcc bug that would evaluate that type to `void` for any `std::insert_iterator`?  Your code doesn't compile -- giving the error that it's trying to evaluate `sizeof(void)`.

Comment: @Drew Dormann If this is your own iterator type I suspect you have to specialize `iterator_traits` for it to know the value type.

Comment: Thats pretty strange, [output-iterators don't have a value-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619551/output-iterators-value-type).

Comment: @ipc (follow-up) I was making a common misunderstanding regarding `value_type`.  It's defined as the type would be **read** from the iterator.  So it has no meaning for `insert_iterator`.  (Sorry - that also makes this answer wrong)