# Is there an elegant way to traverse 2 maps and compare values (maps have same type)

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

lets say I have 2 maps:

```
map<int,vector<int>> id2courses;
map<int,vector <int>> id2allowed_courses;
```

And I would like for each key(id) see if list of courses contains only those courses that are allowed for that id. It can easily be done with a for loop, but I would like to exploit the fact that std::map is ordered, aka I would like to advance in both maps(incrementing the iterator with smaller key) and when I hit equal keys then I would like to do the comparisons.
I know I can do it with nontrivial while loop, but I wonder is there a builtin STL way to do it

Comment: For a key in the "allowed" map, there doesn't necessarily have to be an entry in the other map, or does it?

Comment: You might want to check out [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: @leemes no, lets say I care about the general case, no guarantee that .firsts are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) is a bit of a hack:

```
map<int,vector<int>> id2courses;
map<int,vector <int>> i2allowed_courses;

set_intersection(id2courses.begin(), id2courses.end(),
                 i2allowed_courses.begin(), i2allowed_courses.end(),
                 null_output_iterator(),
                 compare_and_do_something_if_same_key);
```

The `null_output_iterator` is from the question [Discarding the output of a function that needs an output iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/335930/1084416).

`compare_and_do_something_if_same_key` will be passed a `pair<const int, vector<int>>` from each map. If the keys are equal you can do the processing you want. You also need to return a boolean to represent the ordering of elements:

```
bool compare_and_do_something_if_same_key(
    pair<const int, vector<int>& a, pair<const int, vector<int>& b)
{
    if(a.first == b.first) {
        doProcessing(a, b);
    }
    return a.first < b.first;
}
```

Caveat Emptor: The documentation says the compare function mustn't modify the objects being compared. I take that to mean mustn't modify in a way that would cause ordering problems. As you're not ordering by the `second` value in the `pair` I don't think this matters too much.

*edit* for readability:

This could be wrapped up into a named function:

```
template<typename Map, typename KeyValueProcessor> 
void process_values_for_matching_keys(
    Map& map1, Map& map2, KeyValueProcessor& keyValueProcessor);
```

And used as:

```
process_pairs_for_matching_keys(id2courses, i2allowed_courses, doProcessing);
```

Comment: Interestingly, using [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) instead of `set_intersection` produces the same results but is possibly a little less efficient as there are more assignments to the `null_output_iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of [set_intersection()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/), but this implementation, though easier to read will be not be as well performing. I would use a cycle and increment two iterators over the two maps. I don't think there is a faster solution. Even if there is something built-in it will perform at it best as good as this naive solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't it perform well?

Comment: set_intersection does one iteration over both containers. Next he will have to do another one to perform he wants on each of the elements to check for a given property. OP can do all that in a single iteration.

Comment: I was imagining hacking the comparison function to perform the action. See my answer

Comment: @PeterWood I would challenge if that is more elegant than implementing two loops. Still it is helpful to know there is such option.

Comment: Set intersection need the values in the list to be sorted.and the Op wants the comparision of values when there is a match in the keys.So even if you use set intersection its not reducing the effort in traversing the maps.

Comment: @sarathi it seems to me that not all keys are present in both maps so set_intersection will only leave the keys present in both maps. This will make the cycle much more elegant - two iterators that you increase on each iteration. Please note my answer still focuses on the fact that OP's best option is to do the cycles, not to use `set_intersection`.

Comment: but Op did not mention about the sort thing.if the list of values are not sorted,then you have to again sort before passing them to set_intersection.which will again take a lot of effort on cpu.

Comment: @sarathi please note he has map. I suggest set_intersection for the keys of the map. `but I would like to exploit the fact that std::map is ordered, aka I would like to advance in both maps`